# Unbalanced distribution of tuples despite partitioning with Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

I have a batch job running with Flink on EMR which enriches some data stored as CSV on AWS S3 and indexes the tuples with Elasticsearch.

For some reason, one of the hosts is getting a lot more work than others. I tried to address that by hash partitioning on the several fields of the tuples but this doesn't make any difference: one of the nodes still gets more than the others. See host 40705 in screenshot below.

I need to distribute the indexing across the various nodes as well as possible to optimize throughput.

I tried using *rebalance()* but the result is the same. Any clues?

[image]

**EDIT**

Overview screen

[image]

Comment: If you're using hash to partition your data, it may be like this. But theoritically, this will not happen if you're using rebalance to partition your data. Could you attach the Overview screenshot when you're using rebalance?

Comment: @bupt_ljy thanks, see edit above

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear enough. Could you attach the inside screenshot of overview for the same job like you did with the first attach picture?  I can compare them after I get the information on the same page.

Comment: thanks @bupt_ljy but I had to kill that cluster in the meantime. Will post image when I restart it next time round

Comment: Could you try to provide a custom `Partitioner` via `partitionCustom`. There you can control the partitioning function and see whether you can tweak it a bit. Moreover, I would be interested in the statistics of your data set. Could it be that you have two keys which occur very often?